# Pattern Matching for a value in tuple PHP ( Regular Expressions? )

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having a really hard time understanding RegEx in general, so I have no clue how is it possible to use it in such an issue.

So here we have a tuple
`$tuple = "(12342,43244)";`

And what I try to do is get:
`$value_one = 12342;`

So from `(value_one,value_two)` get `value_one`.

I know it can be possible with `explode( ',', $tuple )` and then delete the 1st character '(' out of the 1st element in exploded array, but that seems super sloppy, is there a way to pattern match in this manner in PHP?

Comment: `(12342,43244)` is a string ?

Comment: Yes, excuse the mistake, edited!

Comment: Why regex? Explode the string with `(` and then the second element with `,`. Or do you mean there should be some validation here? See https://ideone.com/8mQNWY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest `preg_match` example with the `\(([0-9]+)` regex that matches  a `(`, and captures into Group 1 one or more digits from `0` to `9` range:

```
$tuple = "(12342,43244)";
if (preg_match('~\(([0-9]+)~', $tuple, $m))
{
    echo $m[1];
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8mQNWY)

Wrapped into a function:

```
function retFirstDigitChunk($input) {
    if (preg_match('~\(([0-9]+)~', $input, $m)) {
        return $m[1];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/AExq8l)

Or, [to get both as an array](https://ideone.com/7Pek8R):

```
function retValues($input) {
    if (preg_match('~\((-?[0-9]+)\s*,\s*(-?[0-9]+)~', $input, $m))  {
        return array('left'=>$m[1], 'right'=>$m[2]);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

$tuple = "(12342,43244)";
print_r(retValues($tuple));
```

Output: `Array( [left] => 12342    [right] => 43244 )`

Comment: Can I somehow make this dynamic and get the 2nd chunk too? I suppose $m[2] will have `value_two`, therefore will a `$output->left = $m[1]; $output-right = $m[2]; return $output;` give me a tuple in stdClass(); type?

Comment: No, it won't work like that. Will there be 2 int numbers all the time? If yes, use `\((-?[0-9]+)\s*,\s*(-?[0-9]+)` - then you can use `$m[2]`.

Comment: Yes, it will always be a tuple and always 2 ints in it `(int,int)` EDIT: Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to search the number preceeded by an open brace and followed by a comma. The pattern is:

```
 $value_one = preg_replace('/\((\d+),.*/', '$1', $tuple);
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide a function or something I can use that returns it? Would help a million, since I really don't know how to use RegEx

Comment: matching ``\((\d+)`` is faster by a magnitude of 2.

Comment: There is no point using lookarounds here, use a capturing group.

Comment: @horcrux Hmm, the function you provided, returns `2345234234)` it escapes somehow the , ( EDIT: now works, thank you! )

Comment: It will yield the original string if there is no match. I doubt you need that behavior. I guess you'd like an empty result in that case. A `preg_match` approach for *matching* is more natural IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something efficient, try to avoid the use of regex when possible:

```
$result = explode(',', ltrim($tuple, '('))[0];
```

or

```
sscanf($tuple, '(%[^,]', $result);
```